# A simple POST request always returns "Invalid request"

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

This is a very simple post request but I get no data.

This my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://cs.deals/ajax/marketplace-search'
form_data = {'appid': '730', 'sort': 'price', 'name':'sticker'}

r = requests.post(url, data = form_data)

response = r.text
```

The response is:

```
'{"success":false,"error":"Invalid request","response":[]}'
```

How can I get some valid response?

Comment: Just a pro tip: please don't spam with irrelevant tags. Adding `beautifulsoup` and `scrapy` tags doesn't make any sense if you're actually not using these modules in your code.

Comment: you are right, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import json

import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

form_data = {
    "sort": "price",
    "sort_desc": 1,
}

r = requests.post(
    "https://cs.deals/ajax/marketplace-search",
    headers=headers,
    data=form_data,
)
print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "response": {
        "totalResults": 192723,
        "page": 0,
        "perPage": 500,
        "results": {
            "730": [
                {
                    "a": 49,
                    "c": "Sticker | Titan (Holo) | Katowice 2014",
                    "g": 380155439,
                    "h": 188530139,
                    "x": 0,
                    "i": 100000,
                    "k": "8847ff",
                    "q": "MTA3OTEw",
                    "o": "Sticker",
                    "t": 27099487,
                    "v": [
                        {
                            "f": "28274420298",
                            "u": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "b1": "9828591403546145955",
                    "order": 0,
                    "e": 6
                },
...
```